# Есть ли стандартный способ получить id из адресной строки - пути url? Django

Tags: django

у меня в пути есть id.  /order/6/

Как мне в этом view в get_context_data и в form_valid получить id из пути?

views.py

```
class CustomerView(CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'order_cz.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index_cz')
    success_msg = 'Сообщение отправлено'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        now_id = ?
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        now_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        now_id = ?
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
path('order/<int:pk>/', views.CustomerView.as_view(), name='order_cz'),
```

Comment: 1. как выглядит `url pattern`? 2. где именно (в каком методе?)? нужно получить айди?

Comment: @Dima добавил изменения

Comment: В `get_context_data` попробуй `kwargs.get('pk')`

Comment: А в `form_valid` - `self.kwargs.get('pk')`